# How to send sort using dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with sorting some data in my page. Here is the snippet:

```
<form name=frm action="" method="post" style="display: inherit;">
    <label>
       Эрэмбэ:
       <select class="input-select" name="qryorder" onchange="document.frm.submit()">
          <option value="asc">Price ascending</option>
          <option value="desc">Price descending</option>
       </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

Here is the data i want to sort:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['qryorder'])) {
        $sort = $_POST['qryorder'];
        sort_by_price($sort);
        // header('Location: product.php');
    }
?>
```

And my function:

```
  function sort_by_price($sort)
{
    global $conn;

    $sql = "select * from product order by price = '{$sort}'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $list = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

What i exactly want is i need to sort some data ordered by price ascending and descending.

Comment: what is data you want to sort? Please explain more your issue.

Comment: I edit my question i want to sort that datas as price ascending and descending with select option

Comment: Show us your php code, bcz that it the one which does this sorting by altering mysql query. In MySQL query you have to change order by clause.

Comment: @JitendraYadav i 've edited my question take a look.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing the sorting this way. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use whitelist. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `=` operator in you order by clause.

Reference: [Sorting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

```
$sql = "select * from product order by price $sort";
```

**Updated Code**:
Price field in table was VARCHAR which was causing incorrect sorting, converted into BIGINT.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in G:\development\tgnm\includes\functions.php:334 Stack trace: #0 G:\development\tgnm\product.php(5): sort_by_price('desc') #1 {main} thrown in G:\development\tgnm\includes\functions.php on line 334

Comment: check my updated answer, I forget to remove curly braces.

Comment: ctrl + f5 and then try changing sorting from dropdown

Comment: i cannot loading my page.